# How can I factor the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+x^2-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> How can I factor the polynomial $x^4-2x^3+x^2-1$?

This is an exercise in algebra. I have the solution showing that 
$$
x^4-2x^3+x^2-1=(x^2-x-1)(x^2-x+1).
$$

But the solution does not show any details. Using the distributive property I can check that this is indeed true:
$$
\begin{align}
&(x^2-x-1)(x^2-x+1)\\
&=x^2(x^2-x+1)-x(x^2-x+1)-(x^2-x+1)\\
&=x^4-x^3+x^2-x^3+x^2-x-x^2+x-1\\
&=x^4-2x^3+x^2-1,
\end{align}
$$

but I can't figure out the steps to get there. Can anyone help?

Comment: Write $x^4-2x^3+x^2 = x^2(x^2-2x+1)=x^2(x-1)^2$.

Comment: what about the -1 at the end?

Comment: @Icy107 Have you heard of difference of squares?

Comment: As a difference of squares.  One of the squares matches the formula $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$, the other square that's subtracted from the first one is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s examine the first three terms of your quartic$$y=x^4-2x^3+x^2-1$$The coefficients are in the order of $1,-2,1$. Thus$$\begin{align*}x^4-2x^3+x^2-1 & =x^2(x^2-2x+1)-1\\ & =x^2(x-1)^2-1\\ & =\left[x(x-1)-1\right]\left[x(x-1)+1\right]\\ & =(x^2-x-1)(x^2-x+1)\end{align*}$$where the second to last step is obtained with the difference of squares factorization.

Comment: Nice answer! $(+1)$

Answer (score 2):

As @MathLover suggests, use the factorization $$x^4-2x^3+x^2=x^2(x-1)^2=(x(x-1))^2.$$ Now use the fact that it is of the form $y^2-1$ to factor it as the difference of squares.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that for all values $a$ and $b$, $$(a + b)^2 = (a + b)(a + b)$$ which we then [*FOIL*](http://www.mathwords.com/f/foil_method.htm) to work out that $$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab$$

Because the last term on the furthest $RHS$ (*Right Hand Side* of the equation) being $2ab$ is a multiple of $2$, if you have an equation for example:

$$x^2 + 6x = 7$$

What you do to solve for $x$ is *divide* $6$ by $2$ and then add the square of the result.

$$x^2 + 6x + \bigg(\frac{6}{2}\bigg)^2 - 9 = 7$$

Here we also subtract $9$ since $\dfrac{6}{2} = 3$ and $3^2 = 9$, because we do not want to change the $RHS$.  And now, we can factor the $LHS$ (*Left Hand Side* of the equation):

$$\underbrace{x^2 + 6x + 9}_{(x + 3)^2} - 9 = 7 \Rightarrow (x + 3)^2 - 9 = 7 \Rightarrow (x + 3)^2 = 7 + 9 = 16 \Rightarrow x + 3 = \pm \sqrt{16} = \pm 4 \ \ \ \ \ \therefore \ \ x = 1 \quad \text{ or } \quad x = -7$$

You can also solve for $x$ using the [*Quadratic Formula*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) as an alternative method by re-writing the equation as $x^2 + 6x - 7 = 0$, but this does not help us know how to factor. The technique that I showed you instead, however, is known as [*Completing the Square*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/quadequationshirev2.shtml).

---

So now let's see where your equation fits. We have $$x^4 - 2x^3 + x^2 - 1$$ Since $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \Rightarrow (a - b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab$, we can rearrange the terms. $$x^4 - 2x^3 + x^2 - 1 = \underbrace{(x^2)^2 + x^2 - 2\cdot x^2\cdot x}_{(x^2 - x)^2} - 1 = (x^2 - x)^2 - 1$$ Now we can [*expand the bracket*](https://mathspace.co/learn/world-of-maths/algebra/distributive-law-non-linear-terms-6702/expanding-brackets-295/) of $x^2 - x$ (simply, *expand* $x^2 - x$) so that $x^2 - x = x(x - 1)$, thus we have $$[x(x - 1)]^2 - 1$$ And now we can actually use a seperate rule: $$a^2 - b^2 = (a + b)(a - b)$$ since $1 = 1^2$. $$\begin{align} \therefore [x(x - 1)]^2 - 1 &= [x(x - 1)]^2 - 1^2 \\ &= \big[[x(x - 1)] + 1\big]\big[[x(x - 1) - 1\big] \\ &= (x^2 - x + 1)(x^2 - x - 1) \\ &= (x^2 - x - 1)(x^2 - x + 1) \qquad \color{green}{\checkmark} \end{align}$$
Remember that these rules are called *Binomial Formulas* (or *Formulae*) derived from the [*Binomial Theorem*](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/binomial.htm) (or go [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/binomial-theorem.html) instead if you found the previous link too difficult to understand) and there you go! In fact, since the equation you want to factor has *all* of its terms being a product of $x$ (apart from $1$ of course), you can expand the entire equation and re-write it as $x\cdot c - 1$ for some value $c$. Then use the binomial formulas to factor $c$ and go from there! So there are two ways to complete the problem!

After you have completed the problem yourself, try and factor $a^3 - b^3$ to improve your knowledge! If you don't know, tap/click the yellow box below for the answer or go [here](https://www.tiger-algebra.com/drill/a~3-b~3=0/)!

> > $$a^3 - b^3 = (a - b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$$

Another way to factor $a^3 - b^3$ that is seperate to the link provided is shown below if needed.

> $$\frac{a^3 - b^3}{a - b} = \frac{a^3 - ba^2 + ba^2 - b^3}{a - b} = a^2 + \frac{ba^2 - b^3}{a - b} = a^2 + ab + \frac{b^2a - b^3}{a - b} = a^2 + ab + b^2$$

:)

Comment: You should also include the factorization of $a^3-b^3$, but hide it with the `>!`

Comment: @Crescendo haha thanks man!! =D